# Why getElementById doesn't work in this case?

Tags: php, dom, getelementbyid

I have piece of PHP code.

PHP:

```
$Implementation = new DOMImplementation();
$Document = $Implementation->createDocument( NULL, NULL, $Implementation->createDocumentType( 'html' ) );
$Document->encoding = 'utf-8';
$Document->loadXML( $main_html[ 'main' ] ); // load main.html
$Document->xinclude();
$Fragment = $Document->createDocumentFragment();
$Fragment->appendXML( $main_html[ 'page' ] ); // load page.html
$Document->getElementById( 'content' )->appendChild( $Fragment );
...
```

Everything works well except last line, appears error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object
```

It seems `getElementById()` method doesn't work for `$Document`.

Look at the HTML.

HTML (main.html):

```
...
    </head>
    <body xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
        <xi:include href="wrapper.html" />
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML (wrapper.html):

```
<section
    id="wrapper"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="header.html" />
    <xi:include href="nav.html" />
    <xi:include href="content.html" />
    <xi:include href="aside.html" />
    <xi:include href="footer.html" />
</section>
```

HTML (content.html):

```
<section id="content" />
```

I added `$Document->validateOnParse = TRUE;` before `$Document->loadXML( $main_html[ 'main' ] );` and tested without XInclude, but doesn`t work.

Finally I found the solution, bad line replace with:

```
$Document->getElementsByTagName( 'section' )->item( 1 )->appendChild( $Fragment );
```

`getElementsByTagName()` method works for `$Document` but doesn't satisfy me. Did I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a DTD which defines the `id` attribute. Otherwise, you cannot use `getElementById`.

For more information, see:

- http://nl.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and got the same answer mentioned above. Since I don't know how to define a DTD I got the following solution:

Change the HTML code:

```
<section id="content" />
```

into

```
<section xml:id="content" />
```

If you still need the id attribute to apear (for Javascript purposes) you can use the following code:

```
<section id="content" xml:id="content" />
```

I ran into another problem with this solution since xml:id attribute won't pass validator.
My solution for this problem was as follows: Leave the HTML code as is:

```
<section id="content" />
```

Now change your PHP code like this:

```
/* ... Add xml:id tags */

$tags = $Document -> getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach ($tags as $tag)
  $tag->setAttribute('xml:id',$tag->getAttribute('id'));

/* ... Here comes your PHP code */

$Document->getElementById( 'content' )->appendChild( $Fragment );

/* ... Remove xml:id tags */

foreach ($tags as $tag)
  $tag->removeAttribute('xml:id');
```

This solution works perfect for me. I hope you find it useful as well :)