# Document::getElementById('content') doesn't work, but the element is there

Tags: php, dom

I'm using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for DOM manipulation, but I'm encountering a problem with the usage of the getElementById() method. I'm looking for a div with the id 'content', but this returns NULL:

```
$element = $document->getElementById('content');

if($element instanceof DOMElement)
{
    // do something
}
```

However, the following piece of code *does* return the element I'm looking for:

```
$elements = $document->getElementsByTagName('div'); 
foreach($elements as $element)
    {
        if($element->getAttribute('id') == 'content')
        {
                // do something
                break;
        }
    }
```

I may be overlooking something simple, but those 2 pieces of code look identical to me. (Or at least should work identically.) The second piece of code is operational now, but it does feel wrong to keep it that way. I'd like to know why the first piece of code fails to return the correct element, when the second method succeeds.

Comment: Can you verify in your second example at the `// do something` point that it is indeed an `instanceof DOMElement` - perhaps it's being reported as something else?

Comment: @KirenSiva $document is probably new DomDocument;

Comment: Yes, $element within the loop is an instance of DOMElement. In the first snippet, $element equals NULL. The variable $document is an instance of DOMDocument.

Comment: @Sherlock i found this: "Please note that if your HTML does not contain a doctype declaration, then getElementById will always return null.", by looking for tagname and then the ID of that tag name, it will return the id.

Comment: Oh really! Please add that as an answer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why getElementById doesn't work in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376861/why-getelementbyid-doesnt-work-in-this-case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this:

> Please note that if your HTML does not contain a doctype declaration,
>   then getElementById will always return null.

By looking for tagname and then the ID of that tag name, it will return the id.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php#100402)